# Organise data in table

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a large amount of data available (in excel), which is not very organised. I can do this by copy paste, but I am trying to do this using mathematica. Hopefully someone can help me.

I imported the data, and it is now organised in a matrix that looks like this:

```
test = {{{dog, 5}, {"", ""}, {"", ""}}, {{cat, 7}, {dog, 2}, {"", ""}}, {{dog,3},{horse, 2}, {cat, 1}}, {{horse, 7}, {cat, 2}, {dog, 1}}};
TableForm[test]
```

So on day one, they counted 5 dogs, but no other animals, on day 2 they counted 7 cats, and 2 dogs, day 3: one horse, 2 cats etc.. To analyse this data I want to create a table that gives for each day, the amount of animals but then organised in columns per animal (even if the animal is not present at that day) like this:

```
result = {{"dog", "cat", "horse"} , {5, "", ""}, {2, 7, ""}, {3, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 7}};
TableForm[result]
```

I tried somethings using `pick` and `sort` but could not figure out how to do this.
Of course this example is very simple, but the real data are for a 978x15 table (and does not involve animals ;) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps like this:

```
test = {{{dog, 5}, {"", ""}, {"", ""}}, {{cat, 7}, {dog, 2}, {"", 
     ""}}, {{dog, 3}, {horse, 2}, {cat, 1}}, {{horse, 7}, {cat, 
     2}, {dog, 1}}};

rules = Map[#[[1]] -> #[[2]] &, test, {2}];    
types = DeleteDuplicates[Cases[rules, _Symbol, Infinity]];    
fill = # -> "" & /@ types;    
tab = Transpose[# /. rules /. fill & /@ types];    
Grid[Prepend[tab, types]]
```

[image]

The `fill` part could be left out if your list were more structured, but then more straightforward solutions would present themselves anyway.

Comment: Why not include a column for "day"?

Comment: Thanks for your help! Could not have found that myself I think. Day could be included, but is not necessary for the purpose of the data

Comment: @user9022 you are welcome. If you go through the code line by line and look at the intermediate results, it should become less cryptic.

Comment: @DavidCarraher I left that out because it would further obfuscate the code (plus it would call for an additional `Table`,`MapIndexed` or `Range` etc.).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a one-liner....

```
Table[First[Cases[test[[i]], {animal, ct_} :> ct] /. {} -> {0}],
  {i, Length@test}, {animal, {dog, cat, horse}}]~Prepend~{dog, cat, horse} // Grid
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer!

Answer (score 1):

**Using `Lookup`:**

```
test = {{{dog, 5}, {"", ""}, {"", ""}}, {{cat, 7}, {dog, 2}, {"", 
     ""}}, {{dog, 3}, {horse, 2}, {cat, 1}}, {{horse, 7}, {cat, 
     2}, {dog, 1}}};

rules = Rule @@@ # & /@ test /. HoldPattern["" -> ""] :> Nothing

Prepend[Transpose@(Lookup[rules, #, 0] & /@ {dog, cat, horse})
  , ToString /@ {dog, cat, horse}
  ] // Grid
```

$\begin{array}{ccc}
 \text{dog} & \text{cat} & \text{horse} \\
 5 & 0 & 0 \\
 2 & 7 & 0 \\
 3 & 1 & 2 \\
 1 & 2 & 7 \\
\end{array}$